# ef core ToListAsync collectionview does not support changes

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-core

annoying issue with async that would be nice to resolve...

Running ef core get `_context.Set<T>().ToList();` works just fine.

however, running ef core get async `await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();` barfs... with the exception of "This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread."

to be clear, the `await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync()` itself works, it is how I have linked the results to an Observable Collection that barfs (see _rows in code).

what is also interesting: if I run `_context.Set<T>().ToList();` first; I can then run `await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();` without any errors.

Looked through a few stack overflow posts; tried a few things out, but nothing really resolved the issue. [Error: This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808346/error-this-type-of-collectionview-does-not-support-changes-to-its-sourcecollect), [CS1061 IOrderedEnumerable<TEntity>' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' EF Core 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70109943/cs1061-iorderedenumerabletentity-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-tolistasy) (there were some interesting suggestions).

The view model code has

- ef core (6.0.2) context
- Row property to expose context entities
- Relay Commands (DoTest, DoTestAsync) to run tests

```
public class TestViewModel : ObservableObject
{
   public TestViewModel()
   {
       _context = new MyDBContext();
       _rows = _context.Set<TblTemplate>().Local.ToObservableCollection();

       CommandTest = new RelayCommand(DoTest, CanDoTest);
       CommandTestAsync = new AsyncRelayCommand(DoTestAsync, CanDoTest);
    }

    private readonly MyDBContext _context;

    public ObservableCollection<TblTemplate> Rows 
    { 
            get => _rows;  
    }
    private ObservableCollection<TblTemplate> _rows;

    public TblTemplate CurrentRow
    {
        get => _currentRow;
        set => SetProperty(ref _currentRow, value);
     }
     private TblTemplate _currentRow;

     public IRelayCommand CommandTest { get; private set; }
     public IAsyncRelayCommand CommandTestAsync { get; private set; }

     protected bool CanDoTest()
     {
         return true;
     }

     protected async Task DoTestAsync()
     {
            try
            {
                var results = await _context.Set<TblTemplate>().ToListAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // show message
            }
        }

   protected void DoTest()
        {
            try
            {
                var results = _context.Set<TblTemplate>().ToList();;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // show message
            }

        }
 } // cls
```

The xaml code; key elements are

- Data Grid is bound to Rows
- Data Grid Selected Item is bound to CurrentRow
- Detail Stack Panel is bound to CurrentRow

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:App.Common.Converters"
    
    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:App.WPF.ViewModels" 
    
    x:Class="App.WPF.Views.TestView" 
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=ViewModels:TestViewModel}"
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources/TestResources.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <converters:TaskResultConverter x:Key="TaskResultConverter"/>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel
            DockPanel.Dock="Top"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Button Command="{Binding CommandTest}" Content="Test"/>
            <Button Command="{Binding CommandTestAsync}" Content="Test Async"/>
        </StackPanel>       
        
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="240"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate x:Key="GUIDTemplate">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TemplateId, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:Key="AliasTemplate">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TemplateAlias, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:Key="DescTemplate">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TemplateDesc, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    
                    <DataGrid 
                        x:Name="PrimaryDataGrid"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentRow, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        CanUserAddRows="false"
                        >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="GUID" CellTemplate="{StaticResource GUIDTemplate}"/>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Alias" CellTemplate="{StaticResource AliasTemplate}"/>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Description" CellTemplate="{StaticResource DescTemplate}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>

            <GridSplitter Width="5" />

            <StackPanel  Grid.Column="2"
                DataContext="{Binding CurrentRow}"
            >
                <ItemsControl  Style="{StaticResource TwoColumnGridTemplate}">
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"  Text="GUID"/>
                    <TextBox   Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding TemplateId}" />
                </ItemsControl>
                <ItemsControl Style="{StaticResource TwoColumnGridTemplate}">
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"  Text="Alias"/>
                    <TextBox   Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding TemplateAlias}" />
                </ItemsControl>
                <ItemsControl  Style="{StaticResource TwoColumnGridTemplate}">
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"   Text="Desc"/>
                    <TextBox   Grid.Column="1"   Text="{Binding TemplateDesc}" />
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>


</UserControl>
```

basically, the exception is at `System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)` when EF is updating the entity collection.

The sync version `DoTest()` works without any errors.

Question is: how to make this call `await _context.Set<TblTemplate>().ToListAsync();` work?

**UPDATE 1**

the call to `await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync()` causes this exception to be thrown. (AS NOTED: the ToListAsync() is the call that initiates the exception, but the call otherwise works ok. If I remove the observable collection assignment `_rows = _context.Set<TblTemplate>().Local.ToObservableCollection();`, no exception is thrown when calling `ToListAsync()`).

so the issue is somehow associated with the grid binding to the observable collection.

because the sync ToList() works, the problem most likely has something to do with thread sychronization (UI and await).

exception stack

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source.\n  See the inner exception for more information.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.Verify()
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureChild(IItemContainerGenerator& generator, IContainItemStorage& itemStorageProvider, IContainItemStorage& parentItemStorageProvider, Object& parentItem, Boolean& hasUniformOrAverageContainerSizeBeenSet, Double& computedUniformOrAverageContainerSize, Double& computedUniformOrAverageContainerPixelSize, Boolean& computedAreContainersUniformlySized, Boolean& hasAnyContainerSpanChanged, IList& items, Object& item, IList& children, Int32& childIndex, Boolean& visualOrderChanged, Boolean& isHorizontal, Size& childConstraint, Rect& viewport, VirtualizationCacheLength& cacheSize, VirtualizationCacheLengthUnit& cacheUnit, Int64& scrollGeneration, Boolean& foundFirstItemInViewport, Double& firstItemInViewportOffset, Size& stackPixelSize, Size& stackPixelSizeInViewport, Size& stackPixelSizeInCacheBeforeViewport, Size& stackPixelSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Size& stackLogicalSize, Size& stackLogicalSizeInViewport, Size& stackLogicalSizeInCacheBeforeViewport, Size& stackLogicalSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Boolean& mustDisableVirtualization, Boolean isBeforeFirstItem, Boolean isAfterFirstItem, Boolean isAfterLastItem, Boolean skipActualMeasure, Boolean skipGeneration, Boolean& hasBringIntoViewContainerBeenMeasured, Boolean& hasVirtualizingChildren)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl(Size constraint, Nullable`1& lastPageSafeOffset, List`1& previouslyMeasuredOffsets, Nullable`1& lastPagePixelSize, Boolean remeasure)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridRowsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at MyApp.WPF.App.Main()

Inner Exception 1:
Exception: Information for developers (use Text Visualizer to read this):
This exception was thrown because the generator for control 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid Items.Count:0' with name 'PrimaryDataGrid' has received sequence of CollectionChanged events that do not agree with the current state of the Items collection.  The following differences were detected:
  Accumulated count 0 is different from actual count 1.  [Accumulated count is (Count at last Reset + #Adds - #Removes since last Reset).]

One or more of the following sources may have raised the wrong events:
     System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator
      System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection
       System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView
  *     System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[[Db.Model.TblTemplate, Db.WPF, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
(The starred sources are considered more likely to be the cause of the problem.)
```

Comment: `ToListAsync` has nothing to do with WPF or any UI element. When it's called, EF translates the LINQ query to SQL, executes it, and maps the results to concrete instances of the entity (not table) represented by a DbSet. Post the actual full exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()` or by clicking on the `Copy Details` link in Visual Studio's exception popup.

Comment: EF is an ORM, not a data access library. It works with entities, not tables. What is `TblTemplate`? What properties does it contain? Does it contain UI types that can't be mapped perhaps?

Comment: BTW the question you linked to shows a serious *mis*use of EF. A DbSet<T> is already a single-entity repository, a DbContext is already a multi-entity Unit-of-Work. That `ApplicationRepository` is a *lower-level* abstraction put on top of a higher level abstraction. It looks like it broke the Unit-of-Work pattern too, tried to replace it with database transactions at the wrong level, so now the code is littered with checks for transactions. A DbContext doesn't need explicit transactions. All changes are tracked and persisted *in a single transaction* when `SaveChanges` is called.

Comment: @lkujala: Exactly where is the exception thrown and when? How to reproduce the error from scratch?

Comment: exception stack posted in update

Comment: Year later, lots comments but no solution. What did you end up doing?

Comment: I shelved this approach entirely. Resolving these types of issues has diminishing returns.